# Auto refresh not working in gridview after delete image

Tags: android, gridview, android-emulator

I am working on grid view and i am new in android.I previously had a problem in gridview which i solved myself i am posting the link because the code is same apart from the new functionality added in contextual task
[i dont know how to get the position of the img that i click so i can pass it to next acitvity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378712/i-dont-know-how-to-get-the-position-of-the-img-that-i-click-so-i-can-pass-it-to)
the remaining code is as follow

```
@Override  
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
    if(item.getTitle()=="View"){function1(item.getItemId());}  
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Details"){function2(item.getItemId());}  
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Delete"){function3(item.getItemId());}  
    else {return false;}  
    return true;  
}  

public void function1(int id){ 


    //String prompt;
    // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity

    /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                path, 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("id", path );
    startActivity(i);
}  
public void function2(int id){  
    Toast.makeText(this, "Details func called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
} 
public void function3(int id){  
    File file = new File(path);
    if(file.exists())
    {
        boolean deleted = file.delete();
    }
    myImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //gv.invalidateViews();


    Toast.makeText(this, "function delete called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
}
```

i am not allowed to post image as i have less reputation but when the delete func is called the image is deleted but there is an empty space in the grid view i want empty space to be autofilled automatically after the delete func is called.

Comment: you need to bind the adapter once again ...

Comment: i dont know how can i bind the adapter in function 3 kindly tell the code or any link would be helpfull

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the file from the imageList in the adapter. Without that, the file path is still on the list so the image will be attempted to load and fail causing a empty space.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;   
    }

    void add(String path){
        itemList.add(path); 
    }

    void remove(String path){
        itemList.remove(path);
    }
}

public void function3(int id){  
    File file = new File(path);
    if(file.exists())
    {
        boolean deleted = file.delete();
    }
    myImageAdapter.remove(path);
    myImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Toast.makeText(this, "function delete called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
}
```

Comment: one more thing as you know i have the path of the image in "path" i.e /mnt/sdcard/me.jpg how can i fetch the name of the image i.e "me.jpg" and the date of the image kindly tell me any function or code for this purpose.

Comment: File file = new File(filePath);
file.getName(); // Only gives the file name (me.jpg).